# Simplify:$\frac{\sqrt[5]{5}+\sqrt[5]{5^2}+...+\sqrt[5]{5^n}}{\frac{1}{\sqrt[5]{5}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt[5]{5^2}}...+\frac{1}{\sqrt[5]{5^n}}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\frac{\sqrt[5]{5}+\sqrt[5]{5^2}+...+\sqrt[5]{5^n}}{\frac{1}{\sqrt[5]{5}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt[5]{5^2}}...+\frac{1}{\sqrt[5]{5^n}}}$$

So I know I have to get some relation where I pretty much get the same thing in the numerator and denominator. I guess in the denominator I can put everything  over a common denominator $\sqrt[5]{5^n}$ and then on top of that I get $\sqrt[5]{5^{n-1}}+\sqrt[5]{5^{n-2}}+...+1$. Now the problem is how do I get the same thing in the numerator ?

Comment: It's irritating to realize how close we get.  Put the bottom over a common denominator $\sqrt[5]{5^{n+1}}$ and then on the top (of the denominator) you get $\sqrt[5]{5^n} + \sqrt[5]{5^{n-1}} + ... + \sqrt[5]{5}$ which *IS* the numerator!  So the whole thing is $\frac 1{\frac 1{\sqrt[5]{5^{n+1}}}}$... Argh.  So close... well, live and learn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I found an easier way to do it. As soon as I posted the question it just came to me. I didn't do those geometric series in school yet so I am unaware of those formulas. I just switched $\sqrt[5]{5}$ into $a$.
It gets a lot easier and the result is $\sqrt[5]{5^{n+1}}$ .

$$\frac {a+a^2+...a^n}{\frac{a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}+....1}{a^{n}}}$$
Then it gets easy:
$$\frac {a^n(a+a^2+...a^n)}{a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}+.....1}$$
And Finally
$$\frac {a^na(1+a^2+...a^{n-1})}{a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}+.....1}$$
$$ aa^n = a^{n+1}$$ 
And just replace $a$ with the original square root and thats the answer!

Comment: Good, job!  See my absurd answer for complicated side tracks I went done only to come to the same very simple conclusion.

Comment: Actually that's so much simpler than the geometric series.  It's amazing how many of us (myself included) simply didn't note that numerator and denominater were the same but for a simple factor.  Again, good job.

Comment: @fleablood Math is truly amazing isn't it ? :)

Comment: Yes, and no.  Thing is we had two geometric series $A =\sum a_i^i$ and $B \sum b_i^{i}$ and we should for realized that $a_i = c*b_i$ so $\frac AB = \frac {cB}B = c$.  Must of us were so used to and comfortable with $A = a_i^{n+1} -1/(a_i - 1)$ and $B = b_i^{n+1} - 1/(b_i - 1)$ that that just seemed to be our first defense. They are pretty much equivalent techniques.

Answer (score 1):

I'd convince myself slowly step by step.  by multiplying top and bottom by$ \sqrt[5]{5^i}$ again and again.

$\frac{\sqrt[5]{5}+\sqrt[5]{5^2}+...+\sqrt[5]{5^n}}{\frac{1}{\sqrt[5]{5}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt[5]{5^2}}...+\frac{1}{\sqrt[5]{5^n}}}=$

$\frac{\sqrt[5]{5^2}+\sqrt[5]{5^3}+...+\sqrt[5]{5^{n+1}}}{1+\frac{1}{\sqrt[5]{5}}...+\frac{1}{\sqrt[5]{5^{n-1}}}}=$

... and then I'd realize thats just going to give me

$\frac{\sqrt[5]{5^{n+1}}+\sqrt[5]{5^{n+2}2}+...+\sqrt[5]{5^{2n}}}{\sqrt[5]{5}+\sqrt[5]{5^2}+...+\sqrt[5]{5^n}}=$

which doesn't help me in the least.. oh, well, we all make false starts....

Then I'd remember $(x-1)(1 + x + x^2 +x^3+ ........  + x^n) = (x^{n+1} -1)$.

So:

$\frac{\sqrt[5]{5}+\sqrt[5]{5^2}+...+\sqrt[5]{5^n}}{\frac{1}{\sqrt[5]{5}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt[5]{5^2}}...+\frac{1}{\sqrt[5]{5^n}}}=\frac {\frac{\sqrt[5]{5^{n+1}} - 1}{\sqrt[5]{5} -1}}{\frac{\frac 1{\sqrt[5]{5^{n+1}}} - 1}{\frac 1{\sqrt[5]{5}} -1}}=$

$\frac{\sqrt[5]{5^{n+1}} - 1}{\sqrt[5]{5} -1}\frac{\frac 1{\sqrt[5]{5}} -1}{\frac 1{\sqrt[5]{5^{n+1}}} - 1}=$

$\frac{-\sqrt[5]{5^{n+1}} + \sqrt[5]{5^{n}} +1-\sqrt[5]{5^{-1}}}{-\sqrt[5]{5^{-n-1}} + \sqrt[5]{5^{-n}} +1-\sqrt[5]{5}}=$

$\frac{\sqrt[5]{5^{-1}}(-\sqrt[5]{5^{n+2}} + \sqrt[5]{5^{n+1}} +\sqrt[5]{5}-1)}{\sqrt[5]{5^{-n-2}}(-1 + \sqrt[5]{5} +\sqrt[5]{5^{n+1}}-\sqrt[5]{5^{n+2}})}=$

$\frac{\sqrt[5]{5^{-1}}}{\sqrt[5]{5^{-n-2}}}=$

$\sqrt[5]{5^{n+1}}$

Then I'd realize that if the whole thing would be so simple, I could have made the whole thing a *lot* easier with fractional exponents from the beginning:

$\frac{\sqrt[5]{5}+\sqrt[5]{5^2}+...+\sqrt[5]{5^n}}{\frac{1}{\sqrt[5]{5}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt[5]{5^2}}...+\frac{1}{\sqrt[5]{5^n}}}=$

$\frac{5^{\frac 15} + 5^{\frac 25} +.... 5^{\frac n5}}{5^{-\frac 15} + 5^{-\frac 25} +.... 5^{-\frac n5}}$

Multiply top and bottom by $5^{\frac n5}$

$=\frac{5^{\frac n5}[5^{\frac 15} + 5^{\frac 25} +.... 5^{\frac n5}]}{5^{\frac {n-1}5} + 5^{\frac {n-2}5} +.... +1}$

Oops... not enough.  Factor out one more power.

$=\frac{5^{\frac {n+1}5}[1 + 5^{\frac 15} +.... 5^{\frac {n-1}5}]}{5^{\frac {n-1}5} + 5^{\frac {n-2}5} +.... +1}$

$= 5^{\frac {n+1}5}$.

Then I'd realize that I was okay at the beginning all along, but I should have factored from the beginning:

$\frac{\sqrt[5]{5}+\sqrt[5]{5^2}+...+\sqrt[5]{5^n}}{\frac{1}{\sqrt[5]{5}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt[5]{5^2}}...+\frac{1}{\sqrt[5]{5^n}}}=\frac{\sqrt[5]{5^{n+1}}(\frac{1}{\sqrt[5]{5}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt[5]{5^2}}...+\frac{1}{\sqrt[5]{5^n}})}{\frac{1}{\sqrt[5]{5}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt[5]{5^2}}...+\frac{1}{\sqrt[5]{5^n}}}=\sqrt[5]{5^{n+1}}$

Oh, well.  Live and learn.

Lesson is you *will* get to the end if you keep plugging and math is consistent so a correct answer is  a correct answer and it will come up eventually.

Answer (score 0):

Its a combination of two geometric series $$s=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n 5^{\frac{i}{5}}}{\sum_{i=1}^n 5^{\frac{-i}{5}}}$$ now use the summation to get a generalized result for finite n .

Answer (score 0):

It is a geometric series $$\frac { \sqrt [ 5 ]{ 5 } +\sqrt [ 5 ]{ 5^{ 2 } } +...+\sqrt [ 5 ]{ 5^{ n } }  }{ \frac { 1 }{ \sqrt [ 5 ]{ 5 }  } +\frac { 1 }{ \sqrt [ 5 ]{ 5^{ 2 } }  } ...+\frac { 1 }{ \sqrt [ 5 ]{ 5^{ n } }  }  } =\frac { \frac { 1-\sqrt [ 5 ]{ { 5 }^{ n+1 } }  }{ 1-\sqrt [ 5 ]{ 5 }  }  }{ \frac { 1-\frac { 1 }{ \sqrt [ 5 ]{ { 5 }^{ n+1 } }  }  }{ 1-\frac { 1 }{ \sqrt [ 5 ]{ 5 }  }  }  } =\sqrt [ 5 ]{ { 5 }^{ n } } $$

Answer (score 0):

HINT: $$\sum_{i=1}^n5^{i/5}=\frac{\left(5^{1/5}\right)^{n+1}-5^{1/5}}{5^{1/5}-1}$$